# How to grant access to Events for Salesforce Integration User License?

Tags: integration, permissions, licenses

I have created a profile for API user with the License `Salesforce Integration`. Now, this user is missing an access to the Events object. Following the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.activity_access_user_perm.htm&type=5), I still can not find the checkbox named `Access Activities`. For the normal salesforce licenses there is such available.

How to enable the access to Events/Activities for "Salesforce Integration" license?

Comment: Have you created a permission set for this permission?  By design, the Integration profile does not have various permissions available, so you have to apply them using permission sets.  Also remember that [profile permissions will be retired in 2026](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/permissions-updates-learn-moar-spring-23) in favor of using permission sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps

1. Assign the *Permission Set License* `Salesforce API Integration` to the user.
2. Then create a Permission Set (license = blank) that includes the permission `Access Activities` and most likely `Edit Tasks` and `Edit Events`

Step 1 defines the universe of allowed permissions to be granted to that user

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I have chosen the wrong license in the permission set. It was just "Salesforce Integration" before. Thanks!